Unable to get CsvReaderFormat for Flink read a CSV file
I am trying a simple task of reading a CSV file inside flink execution class using CsvReaderFormat as mentioned in the documentation. I have a pojo called subscriberADSR (I know it is a bad practise to start with small letters, but will correct later)
When followed the simple instruction to create a CSVReaderFormat
CsvReaderFormat<subscriberADSR> csvFormat = CsvReaderFormat<subscriberADSR>.

I get nothing after the . on the code assist. If I use the following I get the below compile error
CsvReaderFormat<subscriberADSR> csvFormat = CsvReaderFormat.forPojo(subscriberADSR.class);

The type org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.reader.SimpleStreamFormat cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.apache.flink.formats.csv.CsvReaderFormat

The following are the pom dependencies for flink and flink csv
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong
I have gone through most of forum questions if anyone reported similar issues, but could not find anything

Maybe if someone could share a working sample java code for flink reading data from a csv file into a pojo would be great. Not able to make this simple thing work as yet by reading the documentation

Did you try this example?
//Has to match the exact order of columns in the CSV file
@JsonPropertyOrder({"city","lat","lng","country","iso2",
                    "adminName","capital","population"})
    public static class CityPojo {
    public String city;
    public BigDecimal lat;
    public BigDecimal lng;
    public String country;
    public String iso2;
    public String adminName;
    public String capital;
    public long population;
}

Function<CsvMapper, CsvSchema> schemaGenerator = mapper ->
        mapper.schemaFor(CityPojo.class).withoutQuoteChar().withColumnSeparator('|');

CsvReaderFormat<CityPojo> csvFormat =
        CsvReaderFormat.forSchema(() -> new CsvMapper(), schemaGenerator, TypeInformation.of(CityPojo.class));

FileSource<CityPojo> source =
        FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(csvFormat, Path.fromLocalFile(...)).build();

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.19/docs/connectors/datastream/formats/csv/#advanced-configuration

Jie, Thanks for taking time to suggest. Though this did not solve my problem right away, but at least made me explore. The major challenge I am facing with flink that there are many things that have been deprecated recently with no proper guidance on how to use the latest for someone who is starting up.
Most of the issues were pertaining to the use of wrong dependencies and wrong versions numbers. It was very painful to solve but finally was able to read the CSV file. But thank you anyway
